# Parameter “currency” is invalid for event “Purchase”

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: 100.00,
    currency: 'MVR',
});
```

I'm using Facebook event tracking in one of our client sites and the browser is showing below error in the Purchase event. 
**Facebook Pixel Error: Parameter "currency" is invalid for event "Purchase"** But it gets logged in the Ads manager as a successful event.

I also noticed that this error occurs only in a few currencies like **LKR**, **MVR** only. If we send currencies like **USD** or **GBP**, the browser shows no error.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in an another post.

You should also modify the value variable within the IMG pixel at the bottom of the code like this:

```
<img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<FB_PIXEL_ID>&amp;ev=Purchase&amp;cd[value]=100.00&amp;cd[currency]=MVR"/>
```

Source: [Conversion Tracking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-with-ads/conversion-tracking)